# How are .lib files structured?

Tags: visual-c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm currently trying to incorporate some libraries into a Windows C++ project. Now I used to assume that .lib files were used for static libraries and .dll were used for dynamic libraries. Feel free to correct this thought.

However, after trying to actually use libraries (whether that be static or dynamic), it seems like you are required for provide a .lib. So that makes me think that .libs are not associated with just static libraries, but also dynamic libraries.

So how exactly are .lib files structured? How can your project determine whether or not a .lib file is associated with a static library or dynamic library? I assume there must be some information encoded into the .lib file that states whether or not this .lib file actually contains compiled classes/functions, or if it doesn't (in the case of dyanmic library).

Comment: .a/.lib files are for static libraries and is an archive. They usually contain a bunch of object files when archived with `ar.exe -rcs *.o` When a .dll is created, there's an import file .a/.lib which contains symbols and info to automatically import the associated .dll. In other words, you don't have to do `LoadLibrary`. Instead, you link against the .a/.lib and include the headers and just use the headers like normal. Without the .a/.lib file, you need to dynamically load the library manually and keep a pointer to each function you want to use. How is this one structured? No idea.

Comment: Try using `ar.exe` to dump the .a/.lib file and see what its contents are.. or a hex-editor.